# Embed Web Page/Frame in Email

Tags: html, email

Is there a way to embed a complete web page into an email?

This is the equivalent of doing:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://www.yahoo.com" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

My requirements do NOT allow to include the actual HTML of the page in the email body (which would be the "normal" way of doing this), the customer just wants the email client to pull the web page from the internet when the email is opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **Don't do it** - it's not supported in most email clients

More information here: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is a 2012 question. The "most email clients don't support this", and the "don't do it, you'll be labeled a spammer" response is incorrect. My bank, Microsoft, many newsletters, and most other businesses link to images on their sites. Right click images in most business emails, click copy image address, paste it into the address bar, and you'll see that the image is hosted on their server. This is why many old emails are missing their images. They've been deleted off the server.

Being labeled a spammer has a LOT more to do with return path certification, and properly setting up your email servers.
https://mail.live.com/mail/services.aspx

Per my host, not all tests have to pass: https://intodns.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it! Your domain will be marked as spam if you add javascript or iframe. I am sure your client don't want that to happen.